# Parse Wikipedia Dump (.xml file)

Tags: ubuntu, wikipedia

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.
I downloaded the English Wikipedia Dump. The `.xml.bz2` file was around 9Gb. After I extracted it using the command line tool, I got an .xml file that is around 44Gb in size. I am not able to find a suitable method to read the content of the xml file. Any suggestions on how to go about doing the same.

I tried [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikidump). I have installed wikidump using the methods stated in the article. The article mentions about `wikidump.cfg` file which I cannot locate. Also how do I proceed futher after locating the file. 
I am relatively new to the Linux working environment. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is goal and why did you download the complete dump?

Answer (score 0):

The are very few systems that can read a file that size as one big chunck. You need a VERY POWERFUL machine with at least 44GB Memory. You should try and split the file to smaller chunks, then you will be able to read it.

```
split -b 1440k my_big_file
```

Is how you can do it.